# Magento2 custom referer URL redirects to correct URL but again redirects to My Account in few seconds

Tags: magento2, login, redirect-url

I have created a custom URL with referer like this:

```
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

 public function __construct(
    Template\Context $context,
    UrlInterface $urlInterface,
    array $data = []
) {
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
    $this->_urlInterface = $urlInterface;
}
 public function getRefererUrl()
{
    $referenceUrl = $this->_urlInterface->getUrl('burger.html');
    $redirectUrl = $this->_urlInterface->getUrl('customer/account/login', array('referer'=>base64_encode($referenceUrl)));
    return $redirectUrl;

}
```

After this I am able to get a URL containing referer also after customer login it is redirecting to correct referer URL.

The issue is that after it redirects to referer URL it again redirects to My-Account, not sure why this is happening.

Checked the admin settings and it is set to NO to redirect to MyAccount after login under:

**CusotmerConfiguration** > **Login Option** > **Redirect Customer to Account Dashboard after Logging in** (it is NO)

Also after simple login process as well (without my custom created referer link) I am not redirected to My-Account.

Any ideas why I have been again redirected to My-Account when using my custom referer URL.